# Updating product properties via DAL - Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

I'm trying to update products(incl. variants) via DAL. The problem I'm facing right now is that if I'm writing the properties, new ones will be added and old ones(even if they aren't included in the data) will stay aswell. What's the best way on updating the product including the replacement of the properties?

```php
$product = [
    'id' => $id,
    'properties' => $properties
];
$this->productRepository->update([$product], $this->context);
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by deleting the properties manually by getting the old `properties` from the current product in the db and creating the diff between the new `properties` and the old ones. I then deleted the old entries in the `product_property` table.

```php
$this->productPropertyRepo->delete([[
    'productId' => $product['id'],
    'optionId' => $propertyId
]], $this->context);
```

If someone knows an easier way feel free to post another answer.